# Nested loop not running correctly inside recruisive function

Tags: c++

Outer loop of nested loop not running correctly inside recruisive function.
Simplified example:

```
uint max =3;
        void func(uint a,uint b,uint depth){

            for(; a<max; a++){ // problem here after first recrusion , counting but not going inside braces with recruisive function
                for(; b<max; b++){ // inner loop works in recruisive function well
                if(depth<2){
                   func(0,0,depth+1);
                           }


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: These are either endless recursions or are never executed (depending on the value of `max`), so this example doesn't explain the problem you are having

Comment: Explain "not running correctly"....

Comment: What is max? Where do you set it to define the base case for this recursive function?

Comment: Sorry , Adding depth limit to example

Comment: If you're debugging, be sure to compile without optimizer.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], right now it's really unclear what the problem is

Comment: I see the problem: you do not reset `b`. After the inner loop executes once, b == max, so the inner loop never gets entered again. Try this: `for(uint b2 = b; b2 < max; b2++){` for the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

**With your initially posted code:**

Unless max is 0, this code will result in a stack overflow due to infinite recursion: the first iteration in a recursion will immediately call the the function recursively starting with a and b being 0 again.

**with your revised code:**

The depth limits the recursion and avoids the endless recursion.

However, after the first external iteration, b has reached max. For all the successive iterations in the a loop, as you don't reset b, the inner loop stops immediately

Comment: No overflow with limiting if statement but problem is that variable a(outer nested loop) never goes higher than 0 , b(inner nested loop works correct).

Comment: @Flow well, you've updated the code so I've to look at it again